# Delete repeated TIME points in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple goal that I want to achieve in my data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  TIME  AMT   
1    0    100    
1    1     0     
1    2     0     
1    2     50
1    3     0
2    0     50
2    1     0     
2    2     0     
2    2     100
2    3     0
```

How do I subset the df for unique `TIME` (i.e. get rid of the repeated time point that has `AMT=0`? To make it clearer: I want to remove duplicate TIME rows that has AMT=0.

Comment: It's not quite clear if you want to remove all the rows where `AMT = 0`, or delete all duplicate rows. If the former, try `df[df$AMT!=0,]`. If the later, use `duplicated()` as per @bgoldst 's answer

Comment: @tospig, sorry, just edited my answer, because I realized I might have misinterpreted the question. I don't think my `duplicated()` solution was the correct interpretation.

Comment: @bgoldst Yes it's confusing, Amer should provide an example output

Comment: @Amer When you have descriptions like these, there are always other possibilities that others get confused about.

Comment: Thank you @akrun and every body. Sorry for any confusion that might have happended. I edited the question to clarify the objective that I want to achieve. Thank you all.

Comment: @Amer your statement `I want to remove duplicate TIME rows that has AMT=0.` is the confusing part as it implies to keep other duplicate rows which are not maximum per ID, ID combinations  For example, If there is a row with `ID=1, TIME=2, and AMT=25`, based on your statement, we need to keep this row as well, and `the `max` route will delete that row.  Anyway I showed both possibilities.

Comment: @akrun Yes, that is true. If the `AMT!=0` then it should stay there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're asking. I think what you want is, for each unique ID value, eliminate duplicate TIME rows, and if a duplicate row has AMT=0, prefer to delete that row rather than another duplicate (with the same TIME value) that has AMT!=0.

The best way to do this is actually to call [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html), and group by both ID and TIME, taking the [`max()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html) of all the AMT values in all the duplicates in a group (thus this will work for duplicate groups that have more than two rows, if such existed):

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), time=c(0,1,2,2,3,0,1,2,2,3), amt=c(100,0,0,50,0,50,0,0,100,0) );
df;
##    id time amt
## 1   1    0 100
## 2   1    1   0
## 3   1    2   0
## 4   1    2  50
## 5   1    3   0
## 6   2    0  50
## 7   2    1   0
## 8   2    2   0
## 9   2    2 100
## 10  2    3   0
aggregate(amt~id+time, df, max );
##   id time amt
## 1  1    0 100
## 2  2    0  50
## 3  1    1   0
## 4  2    1   0
## 5  1    2  50
## 6  2    2 100
## 7  1    3   0
## 8  2    3   0
```

As you can see, the order got a little messed up, but you could easily fix that with a call to [`order()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) afterward:

```
df2 <- aggregate(amt~id+time, df, max );
df2[order(df2$id,df2$time),];
##   id time amt
## 1  1    0 100
## 3  1    1   0
## 5  1    2  50
## 7  1    3   0
## 2  2    0  50
## 4  2    1   0
## 6  2    2 100
## 8  2    3   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear from the description, how we want to remove the duplicated elements.  Suppose if there are duplicates for 'TIME', 'ID', but the 'AMT' element is neither zero nor maximum value.  If we need to remove only the '0' values per combination,

```
library(data.table)
res1 <- setDT(df1)[, if(all(AMT==0)) .SD[1L] else .SD[AMT!=0], list(TIME,ID)]
res1[order(TIME)]
#   TIME ID AMT
#1:    0  1 100
#2:    0  2  50
#3:    1  1   0
#4:    1  2   0
#5:    2  1  50
#6:    2  2 100
#7:    3  1   0
#8:    3  2   0
```

or if the idea of removing the duplicates was as assumed by @bgoldst, an equivalent option using `data.table` is

```
 res2 <- setDT(df1)[, list(amt=max(AMT)), list(TIME, ID)]
 res2[order(TIME)]
 #   TIME ID amt
 #1:    0  1 100
 #2:    0  2  50
 #3:    1  1   0
 #4:    1  2   0
 #5:    2  1  50
 #6:    2  2 100
 #7:    3  1   0
 #8:    3  2   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
TIME = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), AMT = c(100L, 
0L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"TIME", "AMT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```